# Let H and K be subgroups of a group G. Prove that gH ∩gK is a coset of H ∩K in G.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let H and K be subgroups of a group G. Prove that gH ∩ gK is a coset of H ∩ K in G.

so I believe you start with:

NTW: gH and gK $\subset$ of g(H∩K)

if x$\in$ gH and gK, then x=gh and x=gk

since gh=gk

$\Rightarrow$ h=k then h$\epsilon$ H and K

x=gn $\in$ g (H $\cap$ K)

next NTS g(H $\cap$ K) $\subset$ gH and gK

x $\in$ g(H $\cap$ K), then x=gw for some w $\epsilon$ (H $\cap$ K)

then x = gw $\in$ gH

x = gw $\in$ gK

x $\in$ gH and gK

am I doing this right??

Comment: instead of using "\epsilon" use "\in".

Comment: What does "NTW" mean?

Comment: NTW - need to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $\phi: X \rightarrow Y$ is an injective function between sets, then $\phi(A \cap B) = \phi(A) \cap \phi(B)$ for any subsets $A, B \subseteq X$.